# Do a task periodically

Tags: android

I'm trying to make my application to perform a task every day at the same time. It is a task that must be done in the background (upload a file). I use an AsyncTask.
Any idea of how to do the task? 
I tried to do it using AlarmManager but I have not succeeded.

Comment: have you tried looking [here](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)?

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use a `Service`, to upload a file in background at a specific time in a day.

1. For correct scheduling of the Service use the `AlarmManager` class as shown.

   ```
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

   // Set upload time to be 11 am
   cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
   cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
   cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

   // 24 hours interval 
   long interval = 24*60*60*1000; // Or use AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY

   Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourService.class);
   PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

   AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);     
   //Start every 24 hours (once in a day)
   alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), interval, pintent);
   ```
2. Once the scheduling is done, your file upload code in that service will do the job.

Comment: This is an fine solution... but this kind of thing is *exactly* what the SyncManager was designed for.  You might consider using it.